# Why do 6 ft. weapons not have the Reach property?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, reach, designer-reasons

There are several weapons in D&D 5e that are at least six feet:

- Quarterstaff
- Spear
- Battleaxe
- Greataxe
- Greatsword
- Trident
- Warhammer

Yet these weapons(although there may be some incorrect ones in there) do not have the reach property. Why don't they have the reach property?

Comment: Please stop creating the [weapon-property] tag. We have [weapons] and property-specific tags for several of the properties. We do not need a [weapon-property] tag.

Comment: As for your question, where are you getting that these weapons are all at least six feet?

Comment: Historically, greatswords (modern term roughly equivalent to historical zweihander) were only a bit longer than 4ft. Longest war hammers was just under 6ft but that's exceptionally long. I don't know about other weapons but it seems that your question is based on a false premise.

Comment: Oh, and spear in D&D is a thrown weapon. Throwing spears irl was usually 3 to 5ft, not 6 to 8ft as regular ones. Seems D&D just models another spear than you thought it models. What's your source for the length of the rest of the weapons on your list?

Comment: Well then, @Molot, I can assume that tridents are also not 6 ft., correct?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov, I am assuming these weapons are probably 6 ft., which is why Molov is correcting me a lot.

Comment: I was never training with tridents.

Comment: We can eliminate the Battleaxe (it's a one-handed weapon. Seriously. Not gonna be 6') and Greataxe (best comparison is a Dane Axe, which had a 3-4ft haft) as well. The most famous form of historical fighting Trident, the Fuscina of a Roman Retiarius, would have been about 5'5-5'7".

Comment: Hey y'all, if we can't support answers without making just educated guesses based on real-world weapons, maybe we need to close this. This is clearly an answer that requires a designer explanation, not our guesses at what the designers may have been thinking. If there isn't an answer, that's okay, too.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I *cannot tell you* why the designers did what they did because I'm not the designers. But I can give you some historical information that may help here.

So here's a comparison for context.

Of the four weapons you had remaining listed at the time of me writing this answer, the Quarterstaff is the longest one. They are generally about 6 ft long. Just to run down the rest of them real quick...

- [Battleaxe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_axe): This is a one-handed weapon that you can double up your hands on. It's definitely not going to be 6ft long, that would be absurd to use in one hand. Looking at them historically, one-handed axes tend to be shorter than one-handed swords.
- Greataxe: For comparison, see a [Dane Axe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dane_axe#Construction)--which has a typical haft of 3-4 feet long.
- Trident: The best known historical fighting trident is the Fuscina of a Roman [Retiarius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retiarius#Arms_and_armour) gladiator. This weapon is typically rendered as being about as tall as a person--which was about 5'7".

So, the Quarterstaff is the longest weapon of the bunch. Let's compare that to the weapons that actually have Reach.

- [Pike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pike_(weapon)): 10 or more feet long
- [Glaive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaive): A foot and a half long blade on the top of a 7ft pole. Typical total length, 8.5 ft.
- [Halberd](https://collections.royalarmouries.org/hundred-years-war/arms-and-armour/type/rac-narrative-1163): Typically about 6 and a half feet long. But there are documented cases of them being up to 8ft long.
- [Whip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whip#Bullwhip): Assuming something like a bullwhip, these things can be up to 20' long.
- [Lance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lance#Middle_Ages): On average, 9.8ft long

The Halberd is a bit of an outlier--but for the most part, Reach weapons are *significantly* longer than 6ft. And here's the thing to keep in mind...a reach weapon isn't hitting at 6ft, it's hitting at **10** feet.

[Reach Property](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#WeaponProperties):

> This weapon adds 5 feet to your reach when you attack with it, as well as when determining your reach for opportunity attacks with it

and your [default reach](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MeleeAttacks)...

> Most creatures have a 5-foot reach and can thus attack targets within 5 feet of them when making a melee attack.

So, shorter Halberds as an exception...6ft long just isn't the cut-off point for something being a Reach Weapon.

Comment: 10 feet pike? Try **6 meters** or about 18 feet, like a Macedon phalanx. Over history, 10 feet is the absolute minimum what at all is considered a *pike* and the late pikes are even **25 feet** long. On average, 18 feet was the typical pike length under Alexander and when it became reemergent around 1200, while in the days of pike and shot (late 16th century), 14-16 feet was typical. China had typically shorter ones, just in the 9 to 18 feet, but long pikes of 22 feet were used for a time, Japanese Yari in pike formations would be between 15 and 21 feet long, with extreme cases of **33 feet**.

Comment: As for helbards: the measurements are often tricky. While they are cited with 5 to 6 feet in some texts, others claim on average 210 cm (~7 feet), plus in some texts, it is unclear if that measures shaft, bottom to axeblade-top or bottom to tip - which can be vastly different because the axeblade can be about a foot above the end of the shaft and the spear tip can be up to two and a half feet above the top of the axe! The Swiss Guard has halberds of *about* 7 to 7.5 feet in length these days.

Answer (score 2):

### "Reach" means more than weapon size

In addition to guildsbounty's answer I also wanted to add this.

Even though I am no weapon expert in real life and, ignoring the fact that D&D isn't an exact battle/weapon simulator, it seems apparent that "reach" means more than just the length of a weapon.

A "reach" weapon means you can hit someone at a distance effectively enough to cause damage. But could you do that with, for e.g, a quarterstaff?

Sure a quarterstaff may be 6 feet long. But you would have to hold it right at one end and over-extend yourself in order to barely reach someone 10 feet away. This is probably not a very effective fighting stance and you would hardly be able to fight and actually damage someone like this.